# MySQL slow file I/O

Tags: mysql, hard-drive, files, io

I got a little issue with MySQL having slow file IO.

When benchmarking 1k blocks (I did them on purpose that small for worst-case) I get an hdd speed of about 2MB/s.

When looking at iotop while there's a PHP script with many sql queries running it only shows that mysql has about 100KB/s.

In attempts of increasing speed I did this:
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC

The host-system is software RAID1 (mdadm), 16GB ram and a good cpu.

The parition is mounted with defaults,data=writeback,relatime,barrier

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: seek times is a major killer of I/O performance on spinning disks.

Comment: Is there any way to minimize that? With like caching hdd positions in RAM or something

Comment: RAM caching won't speed up disk access but will eliminate the need to make as many disk accesses. Typically you don't want your webserver and database on the same host (partly because this means you have 0 room to scale) and you want `innodb_buffer_pool` to be around 90% of your RAM.

Comment: Do you mean innodb_buffer_pool_size ? Also isn't 14G a bit much?